# In R ggplot2 ,how to draw vertical lines automatically

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-vline

In R ggplot2 ,how to draw vertical line between columns

Using 'geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(plot_data$mperiod)+0.5)' ,it's can't work

```
plot_data <- data.frame(mperiod=paste0('Q',1:4),amount=c(1:4))
plot_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=mperiod,y=amount))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(plot_data$mperiod)+0.5)
```

When using 'geom_vline(xintercept=c(1:3)+0.5)',it's ok ,but i have to input vector manually. Cause in actual, the situation is a little complicated, i want to calculate it automatically. Anyone can help ? thanks

```
plot_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=mperiod,y=amount))+
      geom_bar(stat='identity')+
     geom_vline(xintercept=c(1:3)+0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, that my help you.

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=mperiod,y=amount))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = parse_number(mperiod) + .5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Internally, `geom_barplot` converts the character labels to integers `1,2,3, ...`.　These are used as the positions of the bars.
One way to get the positions of vertical lines is to convert the character vector `mperiod` to factor, then to `numeric`, then they will become `1,2,3...`. Then plus 0.5 (to locate between bars).

```r
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
plot_data <- data.frame(mperiod=paste0('Q',1:4),amount=c(1:4))
plot_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=mperiod,y=amount))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.numeric(as.factor(mperiod))+0.5))
```

[image]

If you do not want the line at the right end, here is one way to do this.
The trick is to minus 0.5 instead of plus, so that positions are `0.5, 1.5, ...`. and use `pmax` to move 0.5 to 1.5.

```
plot_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=mperiod,y=amount))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=pmax(1.5, as.numeric(as.factor(mperiod))-0.5)))
```

[image]